# Rails update has broken uniq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've just upgraded from Rails 3.1.1 to 3.2.2 and I think I've found a regression with `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#uniq`. Thought I'd ask here before logging just another issue with the Rails team!

I have a `Department` model:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :products
  has_many :brands, :through => :products, :uniq => true
  ...
end
```

which was working perfectly under Rails 3.1.1 where doing things like `@department.brands` made a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` query.

Under Rails 3.2.2 the query isn't being made `DISTINCT` anymore. I've tried things in the console like `Department.first.brands.uniq` but that just seems to be calling `Array#uniq` instead of `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#uniq`.

Anyone know if something's changed between 3.1.1 and 3.2.2 that would be affecting this?